# Написать программу тестирования класса и выполнить тестирование

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

не буду юлить делаю лабораторную работу. вот , что я реализовал:

1. создал класс, в котором создается динамический массив.
2. сделал перезагрузку операций ,как того требует задача.
   это всё работает. но есть 3й пункт.

3. Написать программу тестирования класса и выполнить тестирование.
   вот с этим возникли проблемы. есть такая подсказка :

> Создаете еще одно приложение. В него инклудите ваш класс и начинаете вызывать методы этого класса со всякими левыми значениями. Вот и самое простое тестирование.

может кто-нибудь по пунктам опишет , что мне нужно сделать?  или предложит свой вариант решения.

Comment: Ну все же описано. Программа тестирования — которая вызывает методы вашего класса с предопределенными значениями, для которых известно, что должно получиться, и смотрит, получается ли то, что должно...

Comment: Типа if math.sin(0) == 0 print("ok") else print("not OK"). Вот протестировал sin() из модуля math.

Comment: еще раз) 1) я создаю отдельный проект. 2) через  #unclude " файл" подключаю этот файл и тестирую. так?