# Подключение внешнего класса

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

согласно моему заданию нужно произвести тестирование класса. для этого я создаю отдельный проект , но как в нем подключить файл из другого проекта с этим классом?
Visual Studio 2019
c++
Подскажите пожалуйста ,как это сделать?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Написать программу тестирования класса и выполнить тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1469502/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Можно создать решение из двух проектов, и указывать относительный путь к файлу.

Comment: делаю через #include ".../../file" так не работает.